# How to force DUB to use gdc over dmd?

Tags: d

I have both GDC and DMD installed on windows, and am using DUB to build and test my project. DUB automatically uses DMD, but I would also like to use the GDC compiler through DUB. The DUB package reference [here](http://code.dlang.org/package-format) implies you can use different compilers, but doesn't specify how to do it.

I tried just removing DMD from my system path hoping that it would find GDC instead, but now it just complains that it can't find DMD.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You use `dub --compiler=gdc`.

It's documented but somewhat unintuitively. You need to do `dub build -h` (build is the default action).

The same option can be used to perform cross-compilation, e.g. `dub build --compiler=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdc`. See https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/issues/1079#issuecomment-111798195